# How to select the rows with same absolute value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select rows 0, 1, 3, and 4 and other rows with values that have the same absolution values. Note that assume we don't know the values (there could be -25, 25, -2356, 2356, etc.)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'quantity':[20, 30, 40, -30, -20]})

    id  quantity
0   1   20
1   2   30
2   3   40
3   4   -30
4   5   -20
.....
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to filter the rows that have at least 2 times a value in absolute form. You could use `groupby` on the `abs` value:

```
test[test.groupby(test['quantity'].abs())['quantity'].transform('size').ge(2)]
```

If you want to ensure that you have **both** the negative and positive value, make it a `set` and check that there are 2 elements (the positive and negative):

```
test[test.groupby(test['quantity'].abs())['quantity'].transform(lambda g: len(set(g))==2)]
```

output:

```
   id  quantity
0   1        20
1   2        30
3   4       -30
4   5       -20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This exactly what I was looking for. the 'size' string function name confused me a little bit till I found that there are a list of aggregation functions at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation